# Symfony deploy to Heroku error memory_limit

Tags: php, symfony, heroku, sylius

I am deploying a symfony application to Heroku and I get this error on pushing to heroku:

```
Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate remote:131072 bytes)
```

I tried with the .user.ini and fpm_custom.conf file but it seems i doesn't take effect, I have this 2 files located into the root foled and into the /public folder with 4096M of memory limit.

.user.ini

```
memory_limit = 4096M
```

fpm_custom.conf

```
php_value[memory_limit] = 4096M
```

And my Procfile:

```
web: bin/heroku-php-apache2 -F fpm_custom.conf public/
```

I don't understand what I have to do so Heroku gets the custom memory limit.

Comment: What happens when you set the memory limit to -1?
https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors